# How to use native C types with performSelectorOnMainThread:?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, multithreading

I'd like to call `(void)setDoubleValue:(double)value` using `performSelectorOnMainThread:`.

What I thought would work is:

```
NSNumber *progress = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:50.0];
[progressIndicator performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setDoubleValue:)
                                    withObject:progress
                                 waitUntilDone:NO];
```

*Didn't work.*

Then I implemented a helper method:

```
- (void)updateProgressIndicator:(NSNumber *)progress
{
    [progressIndicator setDoubleValue:[progress doubleValue]];
}
```

*Works, but not really clean.*

After that I tried it with `NSInvocation`.

```
NSInvocation *setDoubleInvocation;;
SEL selector = @selector(setDoubleValue:);
NSMethodSignature *signature;
signature = [progressIndicator methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
setDoubleInvocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
[setDoubleInvocation setSelector:selector];
[setDoubleInvocation setTarget:progressIndicator];

double progress = 50.0;
[setDoubleInvocation setArgument:&progress atIndex:2];

[setDoubleInvocation performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(invoke)
                                      withObject:nil
                                   waitUntilDone:NO];
```

*This solution works, but it uses a lot of code and is quite slow. (Even if I store the invocation.)*

Is there any other way?

Comment: `[[progressIndicator class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selector]` can be written as `[progressIndicator methodSignatureForSelector:selector]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are on Snow Leopard, you can use Blocks:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [progressIndicator setDoubleValue: 50.0];
});
```

Comment: Still on a PPC here… damn. Wouldn't that operation be too resource intensive for such a small change anyway?

Comment: Nope -- much less overhead than -performSelectorOnMainThread:.  No boxing required & dispatch queues are extremely light weight.

Comment: Any possibility that you have to wait for other operations to finish before this one can run? That could be fatal for ui updates.

Comment: The main queue is serial, thus you'll have to wait for the other items on the main queue to run.  But same hold true for -performSelector: and other mechanisms.

Comment: Would `dispatch_sync` be analogous to having `...waitUntilDone:YES`?

Comment: Yup -- `dispatch_sync()` blocks until the callee returns.

Answer (score 7):

you'll need to write a custom un-boxing method to wrap setDoubleValue:.

`- (void) setDoubleValueAsNumber: (NSNumber *) number {
   [self setDoubleValue: [number doubleValue]];
}`

Comment: But necessary.   -performSelector*: doesn't do auto-boxing.

Answer (score 2):

Dave Dribin has a [solution for this](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2008/05/22/invoke_on_main_thread/) that takes the shape of a category on NSObject.  His category wraps the method call in an NSInvocation and invokes that on the main thread.  This way, you can use whatever method interface you like, including primitive types for your arguments.

The [Amber framework](http://code.google.com/p/amber-framework/) also has a category on NSObject that adds a main thread proxy, where any messages sent to that proxy are executed on the main thread.

Answer (score -2):

This blog post: http://www.cimgf.com/2008/03/01/does-objective-c-perform-autoboxing-on-primitives/ points out that while Cocoa won't autobox primitives, it will unbox them automatically.  So numbers and BOOLs at least can be passed in as an NSNumber class, and the called function will automatically unbox it.  I've been playing with using a proxy object (Uli's UKMainThreadProxy*) which works quite well, although I'm sure it has it's limitations like anything else.

- http://zathras.de/programming/cocoa/UKKQueue.zip/UKKQueue/UKMainThreadProxy.m

Comment: The author of that blog writes on his first line: *This article is inaccurate.* Followed by *The writer was smoking crack or something when he wrote it and has not been able to duplicate his tests since. This article is left here for historical reasons.* Are you sure this technique works?