# How do I call performSelectorOnMainThread: with an selector that takes > 1 arguments?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, selector

A typical call to `performSelectorOnMainThread:` looks like this:

```
[target performSelectorOnMainThread:action withObject:foo waitUntilDone:NO];
```

where "result" is an argument passed to "action". A corresponding action would be:

```
- (void)doSomethingWithThing1:(id *)thing1
```

What is the correct syntax for calling an action that takes > 1 argument? Such as:

```
- (void)doSomethingWithThing1:(id *)thing1 andThing2(id *)thing2 andAlsoThing3(id *)thing3

[target performSelectorOnMainThread:action withObject:??? waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: Good tutorial on how to do this. http://goodliffe.blogspot.com/2011/01/ios-performselectoronmainthread-with.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In response to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433102/how-to-use-native-c-types-with-performselectoronmainthread) on passing non-objects to a method in `performSelectorOnMainThread:`, I pointed out Dave Dribin's [category on NSObject](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2008/05/22/invoke%5Fon%5Fmain%5Fthread/), which lets you do something like the following:

```
[[person dd_invokeOnMainThread] doSomethingWithThing1:thing1 andThing2:thing2 andAlsoThing3:thing3];
```

for performing your multi-argument method on the main thread.  I think this is a pretty elegant solution.  Behind the scenes, he wraps things in an NSInvocation, invoking that on the main thread.

The [Amber framework](http://code.google.com/p/amber-framework/) does something similar to this, as well.

Comment: Sweet. Thanks for this gem Brad.

Answer (score 15):

You can do it by putting your args in a dictionary or array and passing that to a special function

```
- (void)doStuff:(NSString *)arg1 and:(NSString *)arg2 and:(NSString *)arg3 {
...
}

- (void)doStuff:(NSArray *)argArray {
    [self doStuff:[argArray objectAtIndex:0]
              and:[argArray objectAtIndex:1]
              and:[argArray objectAtIndex:2];
}
```

Comment: it also doesn't work with pink elephants... what is your point?

Comment: @GrantlandChew has an important point -- you cannot naively use an NSArray, you'll need to translate nil values to NSNull. Also I think pink elephants are actually a subclass of NSString.

Comment: The question wasn't about how to construct an array or the limitations of adding nil in one. That is for another question/answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to preserve the method signature of the receiver then I think you'll need to look at using `NSInvocation` which allows you to specify multiple argument values.

You could wrap your call and use a dictionary as a container for your arguments as suggested in another answer but to me this seems like a bit of a code smell.

A better solution along this line would be to create a class that encapsulates the argument values - i.e. a strongly typed approach. So for example instead of passing `firstname`, `surname`, you'd pass an instance of a `Person` class. This is probably a better route to go down because methods with fewer arguments can yield cleaner code - but that's a [whole other story](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882).